# Display the Sale price before Regular price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am a new member and is weak in programer. I want display Sale price before Regular price (as images attach).
I determined the hook here is woocommerce_before_variations_form.
Here is the code to edit in the hook.

```
// define the woocommerce_before_variations_form callback
function action_woocommerce_before_variations_form () {
     // make action magic happen here ...
};
         
// add the action
add_action ('woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_variations_form', 10, 0);
```

[image: images]

Can you help me display Sale price before Regular price?

Comment: Can you share some html and css code related to this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following hooked function code will display the Sale price before Regular price:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'invert_formatted_sale_price', 10, 3 );
function invert_formatted_sale_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    return '<ins>' . ( is_numeric( $sale_price ) ? wc_price( $sale_price ) : $sale_price ) . '</ins> <del>' . ( is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price ) . '</del>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I tested and this works in some products but doesn't work in others. I checked and they are the same product type (subscription or simple product).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r7T6_Q-AKJO2jprmZE6SaB1pvRaqhNeh/view?usp=drivesdk

Example link: https://offer.grow.vn/danh-muc/deal/

Comment: Actually I found that it doesn't work with WooCommerce Memberships discount. So if the  product was discounted by membership plan, it still shows the Sale Price after Regular Price.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using only jQuery and swap to element that show the regular price and sale price:

```
$("#element1").before($("#element2"));
```

or

```
$("#element1").after($("#element2"));
```

:)

> and one more on js fiddle 
>   https://jsfiddle.net/nak73406/v9k7b5c1/5/